# Putting more than one MySQL Row in a column

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, tablecolumn

the problem that i've is, that I have a Table in my Database and want to fetch some of the rows of this table in one column.

For example I've this table names klz:

```
|-------+-----------+-----+-----|
| ID    | Name      | LNr | LID |
|-------+-----------+-----+-----|
| 1     | 0000_01   | 1   | 16  |
| 2     | 0000_01   | 2   | 35  |
| 3     | 0000_02   | 1   | 16  |
| 4     | 0000_02   | 2   | 35  |
| 5     | 0000_10   | 1   | 18  |
| ..    | ..        | ..  | ..  |
| 297   | 0214_01   | 1   | 23  |
| 298   | 0214_01   | 1   | 66  |
| 299   | 0214_01   | 2   | 24  |
| 300   | 0214_01   | 2   | 67  |
| 301   | 0214_01   | 3   | 26  |
| 302   | 0214_01   | 4   | 28  |
| 303   | 0214_01   | 4   | 69  |
| 304   | 0214_01   | 5   | 30  |
| 305   | 0214_01   | 5   | 70  |
| 306   | 0214_01   | 6   | 31  |
| 307   | 0214_01   | 6   | 71  |
|-------+-----------+-----+-----|
```

If I fetch this table with a while-loop in PHP I would get the same table.

So what I want to have is a table like this:

```
|-----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------|
| Name      | LNr1    | LNr2    | LNr3    | LNr4    | LNr5    | LNr6    | LNr7    | LNr8    | LNr9    | LNr10   |
|-----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------|
| 0000_01   | 16      | 35      |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
| 0000_02   | 16      | 35      |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
| 0000_10   | 18      |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
| 0214_01   | 23 - 66 | 24      | 26 - 68 | 28 - 69 | 30 - 70 | 31 - 71 |         |         |         |         |
|-----------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------|
```

This table have the column Name and an enumeration of the possible LNr from 1 to 10 as columns. The data inside the LNr columns arethe LIDs from the table above.

My Question is, how can I put in dependency of the Name and the LNr, the LIDs in the right columns? 
In this table you have listed all Names once and set for all LNr the right LID.

Here is the Code I'm trying to do this with... Until now it works only for the first LNr column, to write the LID in:

```
<?php
  include "dbconnect.php";

  $klz = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT      *
                            FROM        klz;");  

?>  
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
    <table id="grid-klz" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
      <thead>   
        <tr>
          <th> Name </th>
          <th> Leitungsnr 1</th>
          <th> Leitungsnr 2</th>
          <th> Leitungsnr 3</th>
          <th> Leitungsnr 4</th>
          <th> Leitungsnr 5</th>
          <th> Leitungsnr 6</th>
          <th> Leitungsnr 7</th>
          <th> Leitungsnr 8</th>
          <th> Leitungsnr 9</th>
          <th> Leitungsnr 10</th>
        </tr>  
      </thead>

    <tbody>
<?php         
  $name_old = ""; 
  $lnr_old  = "";
  $name     = []; 
  $lnr      = [];
  $lid      = [];

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($klz, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $name[] = $row['Name'];
    $lnr[] = $row['LNr'];
    $lid[] = $row['LID'];
  }     

  for($i=0; $i <= sizeof($name)-1; $i++){

    if($name[$i] != $name_old){

      echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>". $name[$i] . "</td> \n";

        if($lnr[$i] != $lnr_old){
          echo "<td>". $lid[$i] . "</td> \n";

          $lnr_old != $lnr[$i];
        }

      echo "</tr>";

      $name_old = $name[$i];
    }
  }    
?>
    </tbody>
  </table>

    </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
  </div>

<?php  
  mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

I hope you know what I mean and trying to do. If not feel free to ask please.
Thank you

Comment: Do you want group by name?

Comment: yes, but if I do this in MySQL, I would only get one result for a Name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with this query

```
SELECT
    Name AS tableRows,
    LNr AS tableCols,
    GROUP_CONCAT(LID ORDER BY LID SEPARATOR ' - ') AS cellValue
FROM klz
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Now put the results in an array.
Also, get every distinct column (LNr) and row (Name) in other arrays.

```
$ar = array();
$tableRows = array();
$tableCols = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($klz, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $ar[$row['tableRows']][$row['tableCols']] = $row['cellValue'];
    $tableRows[] = $row['tableRows'];
    $tableCols[] = $row['tableCols'];
}

$tableRows = array_unique($tableRows);
$tableCols = array_unique($tableCols);
```

sort the 2 arrays with rows and columns

```
sort($tableRows);
sort($tableCols);
```

foreach row, foreach column, echo value of the multi array

```
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>Name</th>";

foreach($tableCols as $x){
    echo "<th>LNr$x</th>";
}

echo "</tr>";

foreach($tableRows as $y){
    echo "<tr><td>$y</td>";
    foreach($tableCols as $x){
        echo "<td>" . $ar[$y][$x] . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: If you want the columns from 1 - 10, just make that array $tableCols yourself.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I have two questions:
1) why I have to GROUP BY 1, 2? what does the 1, 2 stand for?

2) I get an error on this line: echo "<td>" . $ar[$y][$x] . "</td>";
It says Undefined offset: 3 Undefined offset: 4 Undefined offset: 5 .. Undefined offset: 10 
And this for every name. Is it because the array is empty at this position ?

Comment: i have added 
        if(!empty($ar[$y][$x])){
echo "<td>" . $ar[$y][$x] . "</td>";}
and the error is gone

Comment: @Alex be aware that the if(!empty()) should be inside the "<td>" tags or the entire cell will be removed and the table will be missing (empty) cells

Comment: @Alex the GROUP BY 1,2 does a grouping by field 1 and 2 (Name and LNr). Please read documentation if you want to know more about grouping.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain I understand correctly, but I think this query should be very close to what you're trying to do:

```
select name, 
max(LNr1) as LNr1,
max(LNr2) as LNr2,
...
max(LNr10) as LNr10
from
(
    select name, 
    if(LNr = 1, LID, null) as LNr1,
    if(LNr = 2, LID, null) as LNr2,
    ...
    if(LNr = 10, LID, null) as LNr10
    from klz
) res
group by name
```

The inner part will split your rows in different "LNr" columns and give you what I like to call a "stairway" resultset. All we have to do now is flatten it, which is what the outer query does by selecting max(LNr) for each row and grouping by name. It works because by default an actual value is always bigger than null, so selecting the max for each column will get rid of the null values and give you the actual value.

Answer (score 1):

You can write query like this

```
SELECT a.name,
GROUP_CONCAT(LNr1.LID SEPARATOR '-') AS LNr1,
GROUP_CONCAT(LNr2.LID SEPARATOR '-') AS LNr2,
GROUP_CONCAT(LNr3.LID SEPARATOR '-') AS LNr3,
GROUP_CONCAT(LNr4.LID SEPARATOR '-') AS LNr4,
GROUP_CONCAT(LNr5.LID SEPARATOR '-') AS LNr5,
GROUP_CONCAT(LNr6.LID SEPARATOR '-') AS LNr6,
GROUP_CONCAT(LNr7.LID SEPARATOR '-') AS LNr7,
GROUP_CONCAT(LNr8.LID SEPARATOR '-') AS LNr8,
GROUP_CONCAT(LNr9.LID SEPARATOR '-') AS LNr9,
GROUP_CONCAT(LNr10.LID SEPARATOR '-') AS LNr10
FROM klz AS a
LEFT JOIN klz AS LNr1 ON LNr1.LNr = 1 AND a.id = LNr1.id
LEFT JOIN klz AS LNr2 ON LNr2.LNr = 2 AND a.id = LNr2.id
LEFT JOIN klz AS LNr3 ON LNr3.LNr = 3 AND a.id = LNr3.id
LEFT JOIN klz AS LNr4 ON LNr4.LNr = 4 AND a.id = LNr4.id
LEFT JOIN klz AS LNr5 ON LNr5.LNr = 5 AND a.id = LNr5.id
LEFT JOIN klz AS LNr6 ON LNr6.LNr = 6 AND a.id = LNr6.id
LEFT JOIN klz AS LNr7 ON LNr7.LNr = 7 AND a.id = LNr7.id
LEFT JOIN klz AS LNr8 ON LNr8.LNr = 8 AND a.id = LNr8.id
LEFT JOIN klz AS LNr9 ON LNr9.LNr = 9 AND a.id = LNr9.id
LEFT JOIN klz AS LNr10 ON LNr10.LNr = 10 AND a.id = LNr10.id
GROUP BY a.name;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: what stands id for in this line:


LEFT JOIN klz AS LNr1 ON LNr1.LNr = 1 AND a.id = LNr1.id.

a.id? and LNr1.id?

Comment: I have put 'id' in 'on' clause because it will be needed if you write condition in where clause.